# Patch Stat R for loop question

Tags: raster, r, loop

Below is code for calculating patch statistics on 34 rasters where each raster's name is written as the last column in the output. I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing to have the loop go through all rasters and write their results to one csv. Am missing an i somewhere or does it need to be a raster stack?

Update: when I turn list into a stack and the code below this is the error that I get: Error in `if (m[ii] == 0) minp[ii] = 4 * n[ii]` : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
library(raster) library(rgdal) library(SDMTools)
m <- "Z:/././"
allFiles <- list.files(m,pattern = "_ex0315.ovr", no.. = TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
allFiles<-stack(allFiles)

#PATCH STATS
install.packages("SDMTools")
library(SDMTools)

#Landscape patch analysis
#define a simple binary matrix

for (i in 1:length(allFiles)){
  A1 <- raster(allFiles[[i]])
  # plot(A1)
  A1[A1>0]<-1
  #do the connected component labelling
  ccl.mat = ConnCompLabel(A1)
  ps.data=list()
  #calculate the patch statistics
  ps.data[[i]] = PatchStat(ccl.mat)
  ps.data[[i]][1:nrow(ps.data[[i]]), ncol(ps.data[[i]])+1] <- allFiles[[i]]

}

Error in if (m[ii] == 0) minp[ii] = 4 * n[ii] : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1):

It did not need a stack, I just needed to take ps.data=list() out of the loop

```
m <- "E:/smt/results/"
allFiles <- list.files(m,pattern = "_ex0315.ovr", no.. = TRUE,recursive=TRUE)

#PATCH STATS via SDMTools


#Landscape patch analysis
#define a simple binary matrix
#A1 <- raster("Z:/././W4_2013-04-15_647/spreadgis/results/pt13_ex0315.ovr")

for (i in 1:length(allFiles)){
  A1 <- raster(allFiles[[i]])
  # plot(A1)
  A1[A1>0]<-1
  #do the connected component labelling
  ccl.mat = ConnCompLabel(A1)

  #calculate the patch statistics
  ps.data[[i]] = PatchStat(ccl.mat)
  ps.data[[i]][1:nrow(ps.data[[i]]), ncol(ps.data[[i]])+1] <- allFiles[[i]]

}

a<-do.call(rbind, ps.data)
write.csv(a, "testloop.csv")
```

Comment: I edited your answer to fix the code block and please never, and I repeat, NEVER force a library install in example code. I would also point out that since we do not have access to your data, this is not a reproducible example.